# How to solve this by gauss's method?

Tags: linear-algebra

I apologize if this question seems very basic, but I am self-learning so inevitably there are some gaps I am trying to fill.

In a lecture online, the professor mentioned in passing that I can solve $5-x+2x^2 = a(x+1)+b(x)+c(x^2)$ using gauss's elimination. I know how to solve this by distributing and rearranging the right-hand side so it's similar to the left, but I want to know how to solve it by gauss's when I encounter more difficult functions. I am stuck on how to set this up as an augmented matrix. Can someone please help? (ANS: a=5, c=2, b=-6)

Edit: Here is more context with the complete problem.

Let V = $\mathscr{P}_2$ and $W = \mathbb{R}^2$. Fix the basis B = $\langle x+1,x,x^2 \rangle$ of V. Define the function $f:V\to W$ that linearly extends this.
$$x+1 \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2  \end{pmatrix},\ x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1  \end{pmatrix},\ x^2 \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$$

1. Find $f(5-x+2x^2)$

Comment: You are probably studying linear algebra. Rewrite this problem as three linear equations in three unknown numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$. Then you're text should explain how to construct the matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the question needs more context, i think that $1,x,x^2$ are three lineraly independent vectors from a vectorial space, so you must equalice to zero all the coefficents that multiplie the same vector. That's the only way that this question would need gaussian elimination. Please provide more context...

EDIT:
In our basis $5-x+2x^2=(5,-6,2)_B$ because
$$5-x+2x^2=a(x+1)+b+cx^2=a+(a+b)x+cx^2$$ Since $1,x,x^2$ are linearly independent we get that
$$a=5\\a+b=-1\\c=2$$
We obtain a system of linear equations. I think that here is where you question comes from. Yes, you can use Gauss's elimination method to solve this system by manipulating the equations with sums by rows and columns to obtain a system in the form
$$a=5\\b=-6\\c=2$$
but the system is so easy that you can solve it directly, in fact the only iteration of the method would be subtracting the first row to the second row.
Now to solve the problem:

$$f(5-x+x^2)=f(5(x+1)-6(x)+2(x^2))=5f(x+1)-6f(x)+f(x^2)\\=5(0,2)-6(-1,-1)+2(1,1)=(0,10)+(6,6)+(2,2)=(8,18)_{B'}$$

Comment: I added the complete question. Thanks!

Comment: I am confused on the $5−x+2x^2=(5,−6,2)_B$ part. I understand the parts that come after. But is there a way to solve and get the (5,-6,2)  using gauss's?

Comment: Edited it, check it